# Get the table from cell data

Tags: javascript, html

So this should be pretty simple, but it seems to be making me stumble. I have a drop down in a cell in a table. When that value is changed, I call a javascript function and pass that drop down in the function. How do i get the table from that? example code:

```
<table><tr>
<td>DATA</td>
<td><select id='leadState' onChange='updateData(this)'><option selected='selected' value='new'>New</option><option value='old'>Contacted</option></select></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

javascript:

```
function updateData(select) {
    var table = select.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var row = select.parentNode.parentNode;
    var cell = select.parentNode;
}
```

Why does this not return the table properly?

Comment: OT: But `OnChange()` is impossible or annoying to use if you browse via other means than a mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've forgotten about the `tbody` element (which is optional, but most, if not *all*, browsers add to the `table` to wrap the `tr` elements. Try another `parentNode`:

```
function updateData(select) {
                // select -> td  -> tr      -> tbody   -> table
    var table = select.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var row = select.parentNode.parentNode;
    var cell = select.parentNode;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eJvvK/).

And you really don't have to traverse the `table` for *every* variable:

```
function updateData(select) {
    var td = select.parentNode,
        tr = td.parentNode,
        tbody = tr.parentNode,
        table = tbody.parentNode;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eJvvK/1/).

Assuming you'd like to stick with plain JavaScript, and would prefer not to manually iterate through the DOM while retrieving elements, here's a simple plain-JavaScript implementation of `closest()`:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.closest = function (selector) {
    var self = this.length ? this[0] : this;
    while (self.tagName.toLowerCase() !== selector.toLowerCase() && self.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'body') {
        self = self.parentNode;
    }
    return self.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'body' ? this : self;
}

function updateData(select) {
    var td = select.closest('td'),
        tr = select.closest('tr'),
        table = select.closest('table');
    console.log(td, tr, table);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eJvvK/2/).

Comment: This was it! Thanks. And ya, I added the tr and td variables just to kind of show my thinking of how i was getting to the table variable. I actually do not use them

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, and I'm glad to have been of help! I have added a (very) simple implementation of jQuery's `closest()` method to the answer, to save manual retrieval navigation/traversal of the DOM.

Comment: I am actually using jQuery as well, I did not know about the closest() as I started doing web development just last week. I will look into using that.

Answer (score 1):

David Thomas's answer is probably the best answer.
Although if you have jQuery on your page, you could also use the 'closest()' function.

```
$(select).closest('table')
```

That would account for browsers that automatically add the tbody container, AND browsers that don't.